# Chrome extension to download videos?

Tags: video, chrome, download-manager

It seems Google Chrome is blocking downloading YouTube videos. For example, [Video Downloader professional](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloader-professi/elicpjhcidhpjomhibiffojpinpmmpil) is no longer working.

Please recommend a Google Chrome extension that can download videos.

Hopefully it can download YouTube videos and videos from other websites, like weiqitv.com.

Example: http://www.weiqitv.com/index/video_play?videoId=5541b0709874f026398b4567

As the above website contains videos in Flash, it’ll be perfect if the extension also works on such above pages.

Comment: Not for Chrome, but close enough. [Chromodo](https://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/chromodo-private-internet-browser.php?key5sk0=2128&key5sk1=9b95b003df639e3b85962ef72b5644a5b97d1b14), a fork of Google Chrome by Comodo, comes with the extension `Comodo Media Grabber` which can download videos from YouTube and other websites. It can import all your settings from Google Chrome and logged into with your Google Account as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a chrome extension but a good work around is the [python](http://python.org) library/utility youtube-dl - you need to have installed python first but then you can install it with `pip install youtube_dl` *if you are on windows you can simply install from the [windows executable](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe)*.

Once you are done you can download and save from a number of sites including obviously youtube by simply calling `youtube-dl URL` but you also have a huge array of options.

- Free & Open Source
- Fast
- Small
- Works on mac/win/linux/others.
- Works on 100s of other services

Comment: i'm using a macbook, how shall i install the youtube-dl  tool?

Comment: @athos I don't have access to a macbook but you should be able to open a terminal window and type 'sudo pip install youtube_dl` - if it complains about not having pip try 'easy_install pip' then retry. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Is there a way to install this tool on a Chromebook?

Comment: This tool is a platform independent python script so you should be able to install & use it anywhere that you can get python running see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84160/running-python-on-chromeos for some options to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [downloadhelper.net](http://www.downloadhelper.net/)
Once installed a small icon will appear in the corner of the screen. When you visit any page with a video the small icon will start spinning. You can click on the icon and select the format that you want to download.

If you want to download them as mp3's then I would recommend [YoutubeMp3.to](http://YoutubeMp3.to)