# Browser extension to execute arbitary commands

Tags: windows, web-browser

I have found the accepted answer to [Chrome extension to download videos?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19274/chrome-extension-to-download-videos) recommends a solution with a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface).  I would like to integrate this (and other CLIs) into a browser [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

I would like to find an solution that allows me to:

1. Define a command incorporating a URL parameter. (e.g. `youtube-dl.exe %url`)
2. Invoke the command from the browser GUI (e.g. the context menu)

What I do not want is a solution that involves system-wide macros like [AHK](http://ahkscript.org/).

My target platform is a modern browser running on recent Windows (currently Windows 8.1).  My research leads me to believe that Chrome's removal of [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) rules out this kind of extension. I would consider current IE or Firefox to be acceptable.